# How to correctly stringify and parse a class object containing Uint8Array

Tags: javascript, typescript

When I stringify a class object that contains a property in Uint8Array, and Parse it later, the property is no longer in Uint8Array format.
Here is an example

```
    class Demo
    {
        name:string;
        uin:Uint8Array;    
    }
    
    let obj=new Demo();
    obj.name='Test';
    obj.uin=new Uint8Array([1,2,3,4]);
    console.log(obj.uin);
    //Uint8Array [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
    let StringFormat=JSON.stringify(obj);
    let ParsedObj=JSON.parse(StringFormat);
    let newObj=new Demo();
    Object.assign(newObj,ParsedObj);
    console.log(newObj.uin);
    //{ '0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3, '3': 4 }
```

So after parsing, the property `'uin'` is no longer in Uint8Array format.

Comment: JSON, does not have a type Uint8Array.

Comment: is there any way I can get the desired result?

Comment: If your ultimate goal is just to be able to serialise, then JSON is very limited on it's types, even Dates are not supported, so another more configurable serialiser would be better.  Eg.  https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to turn the values of the stringified **object** back into an **array**.

Grab the values only by using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
const reconstructedArray = new Uint8Array(Object.values(ParsedObj));
console.log(reconstructedArray)
```